# Can you change tab color in Excel Online (Sharepoint) using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Has anyone been able to figure this out in Microsoft Graph?

According to their documentation this is how worksheets are represented:

{
"id": "String (identifier)",
"name": "String",
"position": "Int32",
"visibility": "String"
}

It looks like you can only rename, change the order, and hide/unhide worksheets?

Is there a place where you can change a worksheet tab color.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, currently there is no such api to set the color of tab. As a workaround, you could try to use js to reach your requirement